# What does putting multiple col-size-# in a class do in bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

For example, what would:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-10">
    </div>
</div>
```

...do? How would that be different from:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't the intended usage. The `xs` prefix stands for "extra small" screens. You can mix different prefixes to resize columns for different mobile breakpoints.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-lg-5"></div>
</div>
```

This means 12 wide on extra small screens, 10 wide on medium screens, 5 wide on large screens.

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice that the cols I was looking at had different sizes until I read your answer.